# How to store generic type to avoid internal struct requiring it in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

The problem is best explained with some code.

#### Step 1

```swift
public struct Example<Content: View> {
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    func contentView() -> Content {
        self.content()
    }
}
```

#### Step 2

Now when I add an internal struct, the compiler will complain that static stored properties are not supported.

```swift
public struct Example<Content: View> {
    let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    func contentView() -> Content {
        self.content()
    }
    
    public struct ActionKey: Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
        public static let cancelButtonClicked = ActionKey("cancelButtonClicked") // Static stored properties not supported in generic types

        public static func == (lhs: ActionKey, rhs: ActionKey) -> Bool {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }
        
        public let rawValue: String
        
        public init(rawValue: String) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }
        
        public init(_ rawValue: String) {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 3

To get rid of the error we need to transform it into a computed variable.

```swift
public static var cancelButtonClicked: ActionKey { get { ActionKey("cancelButtonClicked") } }
```

#### Problem

Besides this already being annoying it gets worse. We also need to supply a generic parameter for a struct that does not depend on it at all.

```swift
_ = Example.ActionKey(rawValue: "cancelButtonClicked") // Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred

// Fix
_ = Example<AnyView>.ActionKey(rawValue: "cancelButtonClicked")
```

If we could somehow avoid putting the generic type in the outer scope we can avoid it. However storing the type in a variable won't let me use it. So I am stuck. Does anyone have an answer?

```swift
public struct Example<Content: View> {
    let content: Any
    let contentType: Any.Type
    
    init<Content>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.contentType = Content.self
    }
    
    func contentView() -> ?? {
        self.content() // ??
    }
    
    public struct ActionKey: Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
        public static var cancelButtonClicked: ActionKey { get { ActionKey("cancelButtonClicked") } }

        public static func == (lhs: ActionKey, rhs: ActionKey) -> Bool {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }
        
        public let rawValue: String
        
        public init(rawValue: String) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }
        
        public init(_ rawValue: String) {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Is the only solution to the problem putting the internal struct outside it all?

Comment: Get non-generic ActionKey, independent actually, type out of generic Example type.

Comment: Putting it outside will work of course. But the internal structure would make more sense since ActionKey belongs to Example alone. So Example.ActionKey and to use ActionKey within the struct alone would make it so much nicer than putting the struct outside and calling it ExampleActionKey.

Comment: But that is the part you are failing to grasp. You will never be able to say Example.ActionKey because there is no such type. Example is not a single type. It is a generic! That means `Example<String>` is a type, `Example<Int>` is a separate and unrelated type. You are trying to define an inner type for every one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach (however I'd keep it outside, like `ButtonStyle` is outside of `Button`)... anyway, here it is:

```
public struct Example {
    private let content: AnyView

    init<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = AnyView(content())
    }

    func contentView() -> some View {
        self.content
    }

    public struct ActionKey: Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
        public static let cancelButtonClicked = ActionKey("cancelButtonClicked") // Static stored properties not supported in generic types

        public static func == (lhs: ActionKey, rhs: ActionKey) -> Bool {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }

        public let rawValue: String

        public init(rawValue: String) {
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }

        public init(_ rawValue: String) {
            self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi! Also good tip to keep it outside. On the inside I could use typealias to avoid typing all those long names ;-)